Asking user to select any features in QGIS
I would be like writing a script on the PyQGIS console, that, at the beginning, stops itself and asks the user to select some features of a layer. I mean a window dialog which asks the user to select the features and when this clicks "ok" the code continues again to process.
Is there a web page where it's possible to find an explanation of all PyQGIS Windows dialog?

There is a lot of ways how to do that, depends on what features you want from user. First, you need to show user a PyQT widget with some information and button to confirm. Which widget it will be, you should choose by yourself (QDialog, QDockWidget ...). Important thing: your widget shouldn't be modal.
Then, depends on what kind of features you want, you can create your own way to select features. But easiest way for you (and not handy for user, as I think): just let user select all, what he wants by standard QGIS selection tools.
Then, when user clicks button on your widget, run something like:
    from qgis.utils import iface
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    for layer in canvas.layers():
        selected = layer.selectedFeatures()
        print(selected)
        for feature in selected:
            print(feature)
        layer.removeSelection()

